# Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) - Drag tab from one editor region to another?

Tags: eclipse, tabs, split, window, drag

It's very simple to drag an editor tab to create a split editor layout (2 editors side by side).

For example this may produce the following layout where `|` indicates the window vertical split to produce two horizontally adjacent editors:

```
[TabL1] [TabL2] [TabL3] | [TabR1]
```

Having done this once, I cannot drag a second `TabL` to sit next to a `TabR`. The only options that appear on hovering the `TabL` over the right editor region are for further splits, or to detach the tab entirely to reside in its own window.

The same problem arises when attempting to drag a detached tab (in its own window) into either editor region.

Could someone please indicate how to achieve the desired result?

Sincere thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop a view/editor into an existing stack you need to hover on the tab strip adjacent to the existing tab where you want the new tab placed. You will see a short vertical drop feedback line next to an existing tab.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'd tried this but it seems there's a fairly small area in which you must move the cursor to allow placement and display the move target indicator. Much appreciated!